# vb 2008 set array items with one line code

Tags: vb.net, arrays

hello
Im using `VB 2008`

is it possible to set array items with one line code?

for example, can i do something like:

```
Dim array = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

instead of:

```
Dim array()
array(0) = "a"
array(1) = "b"
array(2) = "c"
array(3) = "d"
```

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following to initialize an array with explicit members.

```
Dim array As String() = New String(){"a", "b", "c", "d"}
```

This can be done with any type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using the below format:

```
Dim boolArr As Boolean() = New Boolean() {True, True, False, True}
```